# Why can't we conclude that $Z_2(G) \subseteq Z(G')$ using the argument below?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$[[G, G], Z_2] = [Z_2, [G, G]]=[[Z_2, G], G] \le [Z_1, G]=\{e\} (*).$ This implies $[G', Z_2]=\{e\}$. Hence  $Z_2(G) \subseteq Z(G')$.
Where is this line of reasoning wrong? I know the conclusion is false because $G=Q_8$ is a counter example.
Also how do we get $Z_2(G) \subseteq C_G(G')$ from the above? The notes I have are saying this follows directly from the Three Subgroup Lemma, but I don't see how. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $[G,Z_2(G)] \subseteq Z(G)$, you get $[G,[G,Z_2(G)]]=1$. Now move in this last formula cyclicly to the left: also $[G,[Z_2(G),G]]=1$. Hence indeed the Three Subgroup Lemma tells you that (again move to the left) $[Z_2(G),[G,G]]=1$. In general, $[\Gamma_i(G),Z_i(G)]=1$. What you can say is that $Z_2(G) \cap G' \subseteq Z(G')$.

Comment: $Z_2(G)$ is not a subset of $G'$, so it does not lie in its center $Z(G')$. What is true is $Z_2(G) \subseteq C_G(G')$. This is equivalent to $[Z_2(G),G']=1$.